# Linux - read emails and run script from gmail relay

Tags: linux, bash, email, ubuntu, postfix-mta

I'm using Ubuntu and set postfix up to use gmail as a relay to send mail following this [guide.](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/configure-postfix-to-use-gmail-as-a-mail-relay/) I can send emails fine but I would like to receive emails and run a script like [this.](https://serverfault.com/questions/261191/how-to-run-a-script-when-a-mail-arrives-in-mail-server-debian) Is it possible to receive emails from my relay and then run a bash script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured it out using fetchmail to grab the emails and then procmail to run a script.

**/root/.fetchmailrc**

```
# set username
set postmaster "root"
# set polling time (5 minutes)
set daemon 600

poll pop.gmail.com with proto POP3
   user 'username@gmail.com' there with password 'password' is root here options ssl mda "/usr/bin/procmail -m /etc/procmail/procmail.conf";
```

**/etc/procmail/procmail.conf**

```
CORRECTHOME=/root
MAILDIR=$CORRECTHOME/
LOGFILE=/var/log/procmail/log
VERBOSE=on
:0
| /root/procmail/script_to_run.sh
```